# Call JavaScript Function from Code Behind #2

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one web control (called `A`) and one web page (Called `Default`).

Is there a way to call a JavaScript function from `Default` that belongs to `A` instead of using `OnClientClick`?

I am using the following in `Page_Load` of `Default.aspx.cs` (This is where my JavaScript function is coming from):

```
a = (A)LoadControl("~/A.ascx");
a.ID = "AgControl";
panel.Controls.Add(a);
```

In Default.aspx I have the following:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
OnClick="Button1_OnClick"
OnClientClick="JavaScript()"  />
```

DefaultPage.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
  String a = getValueofA();

  If (a == "1")
  {
            //OnClientClick code goes here
  }
  else If (a == "2")
  {
     //No OnClientClick code goes here
  }
 }
```

My goal is to remove `OnClientClick="JavaScript()` and code it only in the first part of the "if statement".

Comment: Keven, this is a duplicate to your other question and the answer to this question already exists in the other one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand the other one.

Comment: Why can't you do this in Javascript?

Comment: Because the JavaScript() function is pulling data from the "A" web control.

Comment: Are you trying to run client side code sever side. I.e. are you waning to run javascript in the code behind (C#)?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I want to call the server code which will call the client code.

Comment: The server code will determine which part of the "if statement" to go to.  Then for one of the "if statements" i need to call the client code.

Comment: What does the javascript do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx)

Example:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    Page,
    Page.GetType(),
    "uniquescriptkey", 
    "alert('hi');",
    true
);
```

Comment: Where would i put this?  This would go in the "if statement"?

Comment: The "getValueofA()" method that I have listed is pulling a value from a database.  Would that affect the postback? thanks!

Comment: @KevenDiuliy this will render the script on the page. Yes `OnClientClick code goes here`. You can concatenate the value returned from the database in the "script" parameter, for example: `alert(\"" + a + "\");`